# Expressing numbers using 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

The least number that cannot be written using the numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3, each  exactly once, and any combination of standard arithmetic operations (including factorials) is 41. **What is the least such number if the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 are allowed?**

Allowed operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, factorials, exponents, square roots, decimal points, intermediate non-integer results, concatenation, recurring decimals, and any amount of parentheses and brackets. No other digits besides one of each of 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43766/discussion-on-question-by-bernardo-recaman-santos-expressing-numbers-using-0-1).

Comment: What's an "intermediate non-integer result"?

Comment: Is unary negation allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a start, here is a list of composing all the numbers up to

> 100

(I avoided using concatenation and decimal points, as based on the conversation in the comments there is some ambiguity  if (or when) they are allowed or not.)

> $0=0\times(1+2+3+4)$
>  $1=1^{0+2+3+4}$
>  $2=0\times(1+3+4)+2$
>  $3=0\times(1+2+4)+3$
>  $4=0\times(1+2+3)+4$
>  $5=0\times(2+3)+4+1$
>  $6=0\times(1+3)+4+2$
>  $7=0\times(1+2)+4+3$
>  $8=0\times2+4+3+1$
>  $9=0\times1+4+3+2$
>  $10=0+1+2+3+4$
>  $11=0\times2+4+3!+1$
>  $12=0\times1+4+3!+2$
>  $13=0+2+4+3!+1$
>  $14=2\times(0!+1)+4+3!$
>  $15=0+1+2+3\times4$
>  $16=0\times2+4\times(3+1)$
>  $17=4^2+0\times3+1$
>  $18=4^2+0+3-1$
>  $19=4^2+0+3\times1$
>  $20=4^2+0+3+1$
>  $21=4\times(3+2)+0+1$
>  $22=4\times(3+2)+0+1$
>  $23=4\times3\times2+0-1$
>  $24=4\times3\times2+0\times1$
>  $25=4\times3\times2+0+1$
>  $26=4!+3+0\times2-1$
>  $27=4!+3+0\times2\times1$
>  $28=4!+3+0\times2+1$
>  $29=4!+3+0\times1+2$
>  $30=4!+3+0+1+2$
>  $31=4!+3!+2\times0+1$
>  $32=4!+3!+1\times0+2$
>  $33=4!+3!+0+1+2$
>  $34=4!+3!+0!+1+2$
>  $35=3!\times(4+2)+0-1$
>  $36=3!\times(4+2)+0\times1$
>  $37=3!\times(4+2)+0+1$
>  $38=3!\times(4+2)+0!+1$
>  $39=(3!-0!)\times4\times2-1$
>  $40=(3!-0!)\times4\times2\times1$
>  $41=(3!-0!)\times4\times2+1$
>  $42=(3!+0!)\times(4+2)\times1$
>  $43=(3!+0!)\times(4+2)+1$
>  $44=4\times(3!+(2+1)!-0!)$
>  $45=3\times(4^2-1)+0$
>  $46=3\times(4^2-1)+0!$
>  $47=3\times4^2-1+0$
>  $48=3\times4^2+1\times0$
>  $49=3\times4^2+1+0$
>  $50=3\times4^2+1+0!$
>  $51=3\times(4^2+1)+0$
>  $52=3\times(4^2+1)+0!$
>  $53=2\times(4!+3)+0-1$
>  $54=2\times(4!+3)+0\times1$
>  $55=2\times(4!+3)+0+1$
>  $56=2\times(4!+3)+0!+1$
>  $57=2\times(4!+3+0!)+1$
>  $58=2\times(4!+3+0!+1)$
>  $59=2\times(4!+3!)+0-1$
>  $60=2\times(4!+3!)+0\times1$
>  $61=2\times(4!+3!)+0+1$
>  $62=2\times(4!+3!)+0!+1$
>  $63=2\times(4!+3!+0!)+1$
>  $64=2\times(4!+3!+0!+1)$
>  $65=4^3+1^2+0$
>  $66=4^3+2^1+0$
>  $67=4^3+2+1+0$
>  $68=4^3+2+1+0!$
>  $69=4!\times3-2-1+0$
>  $70=4!\times3-2+1\times0$
>  $71=4!\times3-2+1+0$
>  $72=4!\times3+2\times1\times0$
>  $73=4!\times3+2\times0+1$
>  $74=4!\times3+2+1\times0$
>  $75=4!\times3+2+1+0$
>  $76=(4!+1)\times3+2-0!$
>  $77=(4!+1)\times3+2+0$
>  $78=(4!+1)\times3+2+0!$
>  $79=(4+1)!\times\frac23-0!$
>  $80=(4+1)!\times\frac23+0$
>  $81=(4+1)!\times\frac23+0!$
>  $82=3^4+2-1+0$
>  $83=3^4+2+1\times0$
>  $84=3^4+2+1+0$
>  $85=3^4+2+1+0!$
>  $86=3^4+(2+1)!-0!$
>  $87=3^4+(2+1)!+0$
>  $88=3^4+(2+1)!+0!$
>  $89=(4!-2)\times(3+1)+0!$
>  $90=(3+2)!\times(0!-\frac14)$
>  $91=(4!+(1+2)!)\times3+0!$
>  $92=(4!-1)\times(3+2-0!)$
>  $93=3\times(2^{4+1}-0!)$
>  $94=4!\times(3+0!)-1\times2$
>  $95=4!\times(3+0!)-1^2$
>  $96=4!\times(3+0!)\times1^2$
>  $97=4!\times(3+0!)+1^2$
>  $98=(4!+1)\times(3+0!)-2$
>  $99=3\times(2^{4+1}+0!)$
>  $100=(3!+4)^{2^{1^0}}$

Answer (score 3):

The integers from 1 to 174, and 176, can be so expressed without the need for decimal point or factorial. 175 and 177 can't, though.

[elias's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40382/22922) shows expressions for some integers. In some cases their expression involved factorial or power; it turns out that many integers can be reached using only addition, subtraction and multiplication:

> $11=3*4-2+1+0$;
>  $12=2*4+3+1+0$;
>  $13=3*4+2-1+0$;
>  $14=3*4+1*2+0$;
>  $15=3*4+2+1+0$;
>  $16=4*(3+2-1+0)$;
>  $17=3*(4+2)-1+0$;
>  $18=1*3*(4+2+0)$;
>  $19=3*(4+2)+1+0$;
>  $26=2*(3*4+1+0)$;
>  $27=3*(4*2+1+0)$;
>  $28=4*(2*3+1+0)$;
>  $30=2*3*(4+1+0)$;
>  $32=2*4*(3+1+0)$;
>  $36=3*(2+1+0)*4$;

Reaching some integers without using factorial, power or decimal point entails using concenation:

> $29=32-4+1+0$;
>  $31=34-2-1+0$;
>  $33=34-2+1+0$;
>  $34=1*34+0*2$;
>  $35=34+2-1+0$;
>  $37=34+2+1+0$;
>  $38=42-3-1+0$;
>  $39=42-1*3+0$;
>  $40=42-3+1+0$;
>  $41=1*(43-2+0)$;
>  $42=43-2+1+0$;
>  $43=1*43+0*2$;
>  $44=43+2-1+0$;
>  $45=1*43+2+0$;
>  $46=43+2+1+0$;
>  $47=41+3*2+0$;
>  $48=3*(12+4+0)$;
>  $49=42+10-3+0$;
>  $50=4*13-2+0$;
>  $51=4*12+3+0$;
>  $52=4*13+0*2$;
>  $53=3*(20-1)-4$;
>  $54=4*13+2+0$;
>  $55=43+12+0$;
>  $56=(3+4)*(10-2)$;
>  $57=(2+4)*10-3$;
>  $58=2*31-4+0$;
>  $59=3*21-4+0$;
>  $60=4*(12+3+0)$;
>  $61=103-42$;
>  $62=(4-2+0)*31$;
>  $63=3*21+0*4$;
>  $64=43+21+0$;
>  $65=3*20+4+1$;
>  $66=2*31+4+0$;
>  $67=2*34-1+0$;
>  $68=1*2*34+0$;
>  $69=2*34+1+0$;
>  $70=2*(34+1+0)$;
>  $71=3*24-1+0$;
>  $72=1*3*24+0$;
>  $73=3*24+1+0$;
>  $74=2*(10*4-3)$;
>  $75=3*(24+1+0)$;
>  $76=2*(41-3+0)$;
>  $77=2*4*10-3$;
>  $78=(4+2+0)*13$;
>  $79=2*41-3+0$;
>  $80=1*240/3$;
>  $81=4*21-3+0$;
>  $82=2*41+0*3$;
>  $83=2*4*10+3$;
>  $84=(4+3+0)*12$;
>  $85=2*43-1+0$;
>  $86=1*2*43+0$;
>  $87=2*43+1+0$;
>  $88=4*(23-1+0)$;
>  $90=(4+3+2)*10$;
>  $91=4*23-1+0$;
>  $92=1*4*23+0$;
>  $93=4*23+1+0$;
>  $94=(2+1)*30+4$;
>  $95=102-4-3$;
>  $96=4*(23+1+0)$;
>  $97=103-4-2$;
>  $98=104-2*3$;
>  $99=104-3-2$;
>  $100=10*(2*3+4)$;
>  $101 = 102+3-4$;
>  $102 = (2+1+0)*34$;
>  $103 = 102+4-3$;
>  $104 = 2*4*(13+0)$;
>  $105 = 103+4-2$;
>  $106 = 2*(43+10)$;
>  $108 = 120-3*4$;
>  $109 = 102+4+3$;
>  $110 = 10*(2*4+3)$;
>  $111 = 103+2*4$;
>  $112 = 4*(3*10-2)$;
>  $113 = 4*(30-2)+1$;
>  $114 = 102+3*4$;
>  $115 = (4+1+0)*23$;
>  $116 = 4*(31-2+0)$;
>  $117 = 3*(41-2+0)$;
>  $118 = 4*32-10$;
>  $119 = 123-4+0$;
>  $120 = (4-3)*120$;
>  $121 = 124-3+0$;
>  $122 = 4*31-2+0$;
>  $123 = 3*(42-1+0)$;
>  $124 = 4*(32-1+0)$;
>  $125 = 3*42-1+0$;
>  $126 = 1*3*42+0$;
>  $127 = 4*32-1+0$;
>  $128 = (1+0)*4*32$;
>  $129 = 4*32+1+0$;
>  $132 = 4*(32+1+0)$;
>  $133 = (4+3)*(20-1)$;
>  $134 = 134+0*2$;
>  $135 = (4 \frac12)*30$;
>  $136 = 132+4+0$;
>  $138 = 4*32+10$;
>  $139 = 142-3+0$;
>  $140 = 2*(4+3)*10$;
>  $141 = 143-2+0$;
>  $142 = 142+0*3$;
>  $144 = 3*4*(12+0)$;
>  $145 = 142+3+0$;
>  $146 = 140+2*3$;
>  $147 = (3+4)*21+0$;
>  $148 = (4+1)*30-2$;
>  $150 = (4+2-1)*30$;
>  $151 = 304/2-1$;
>  $152 = 1*304/2$;
>  $153 = 304/2+1$;
>  $154 = 134+20$;
>  $155 = 20*31/4$;
>  $156 = 3*(42+10)$;
>  $157 = 314/2+0$;
>  $158 = (3+1)*40-2$;
>  $159 = 310/2+4$;
>  $160 = (4+1+0)*32$;
>  $162 = (3+1)*40+2$;
>  $163 = 143+20$;
>  $167 = 201-34$;
>  $168 = (3+1+0)*42$;
>  $169 = 340/2-1$;
>  $170 = 10*34/2$;
>  $171 = 340/2+1$;
>  $172 = 142+30$;
>  $173 = 204-31$;
>  $174 = (4+2)*(30-1)$;
>  $176 = 210-34$

Reaching some integers without factorial or decimal point entails using a power:

> $89 = 3^4+10-2$;
>  $107 = 10^2+4+3$;
>  $130 = 2*(4^3+1+0)$;
>  $131 = 132-4^0$;
>  $137 = 201-4^3$;
>  $149 = 140+3^2$;
>  $161 = 2*3^4-1+0$;
>  $164 = 2*(3^4+1+0)$;
>  $165 = 13^2-4+0$;
>  $166 = 102+4^3$;

175 and 177 can be expressed by dint of using a decimal point, but cannot be obtained using just addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, powers and concatenation.

> $175 = (34+1)/.2$;
>  $177 = (2+4-.1)*30$

Even if decimal point is allowed, 178 cannot be obtained.