# Create all numbers from 0-100 only using all of 1,2,3,4 and 5

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Create all numbers from 0-100 only using 1,2,3,4 and 5. No repeats and you have to use each number. Also, you can use any operation. I've only gotten to 50 by pure brute force. I think that this might be fun for you puzzlers!

Also, could someone please help with tags and wording of this puzzle. I know this is similar [Expressing numbers using 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40339/expressing-numbers-using-0-1-2-3-and-4) but I'm still posting this.

Note: You may not use concatenation to combine digits. Ex 1 and 2 to get 21 or 12

Comment: The question you linked is similar, but not identical; that one asked for the lowest number that *couldn't* be made from those five numbers. A couple of things, do the numbers have to stay in the order 1-2-3-4-5? Can we concatenate (for example, combining 1 and 2 into 12)?

Comment: The original problem said that we can not use "glue" and combine digits or this would be really easy...

Comment: Should I delete this? So sorry, I am new.

Comment: don't because I already started on it :d. You can add that "no glue" restriction also.

Comment: The question is awesome, and deserves to be like a new FizzBuzz test that includes recursion!

Comment: Allan, did you make this question up or did it come from somewhere else? If the latter, please add proper attribution to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Also, you can use any operation.

Ok then.

$\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} 5 \right) \\
1 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt 5 \right) \\
2 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt 5\,} \right) \\
3 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,} \right) \\
4 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
5 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
6 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
7 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
8 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
9 & \log_{\frac1 2} \left( \log_{4!!-3} \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt 5\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,}\,} \right) \\
\\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$

---

> would you mind running me through this solution?

This is because for *any* number $x$ (and in my examples, $4!!-3=5$)

$$\log_\frac12\left[\log_x\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots\sqrt{x\,}\,}\,}}_\text{n square roots}\right]\equiv n$$

And the reason this is true

$$
\begin{align}
& a^b=c\implies \log_a c = b \\
& \sqrt x = x^{\frac12} \\
& \sqrt{\sqrt x} = x^{\frac14} \\
& \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt x}} = x^{\frac18} \\
\vdots \\
& \log_x \sqrt{\sqrt x} = \frac14 \\
& \log_\frac12 \left[ \log_x \sqrt{\sqrt x} \right] = \log_\frac12 \left(\frac14\right) = 2 \impliedby \left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac14
\end{align}
$$

See what happens when you add another square root.

Comment: Nice idea! Thats really cool!

Comment: For the less math-ept - would you mind running me through this solution?

Comment: What operation is `!!`? I had assumed factorial - factorial, but this makes for a very large number.

Comment: I don't know what's going on in this answer (especially because of the `!!` operator) but [wow](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRhpV18e7z0/hqdefault.jpg). Kudos.

Comment: @JamesWebster https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: This is both brilliant and beautiful.

Comment: Just to clear all confusion, 4!! = 4*2 = 8 Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: Unless you came up with this on your own, you should probably give credit to the person who first came up with the concept for a similar puzzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours#Rules

Answer (score 40):

$\begin{align}
0 & = (1 + 2 - 3) \times (4 + 5) \\  
1 & = 1 + (2+3-5) \times 4 \\
2 & = 2 + (1+3-4) \times 5 \\
3 & = 1 -2+3-4+5 \\
4 & = 1 \times (2+3-5) + 4 \\
5 & = 1-2-3+4+5 \\
6 & = 5+1 \times (2+3-4) \\
7 & = 5+2 \times (4-3) \times 1 \\
8 & = 5+3 \times (4-2-1) \\
9 & = 5+3 + (4-2-1) \\
10 & = 5+4 + (3-2) \times 1 \\
11 & = 5+4 + (3-2) + 1 \\
12 & = 5+4+3 \times (2-1) \\
13 & = 5+4+3 + 2-1 \\
14 & = 5+4+3 + 2 \times 1 \\
15 & = 5+4+3 + 2 + 1 \\
16 & = 5+3 + 4 \times 2 \times 1 \\
17 & = 5+3 + 4 \times 2 + 1 \\
18 & = 5 + 4 + 3 ^ 2 \times 1 \\
19 & = 5 + 4 + 3 ^ 2 + 1 \\
20 & = 5 \times 4 \times (3 - 2) \times 1 \\
21 & = 5 \times 4 \times (3 - 2) + 1 \\
22 & = 5 \times 4 + 3 - 2 + 1 \\
23 & = 5 \times 4 + 3 \times (2 - 1) \\
24 & = 5 \times 4 + 3 + (2 - 1) \\
25 & = 5^{4-3+2-1} \\
26 & = (5 + 4 + 3 + 1) \times 2 \\
27 & = 3 \times (4-1) \times (5-2) \\
28 & = (5\times 3 - 1) \times \frac{4}{2} \\
29 & = 5 \times 3 \times \frac{4}{2} - 1 \\
30 & = 5 \times 3 \times \frac{4}{2} \times 1 \\
31 & = 5 \times 3 \times \frac{4}{2} + 1 \\
32 & = 2^5 + 4 -3 - 1 \\
33 & = 2^5 + 4 - 3 \times 1 \\
34 & = 2^5 + 4 - 3 + 1 \\
35 & = (3 + 4) \times 5 \times (2-1) \\
36 & = (3 + 4) \times 5 + (2-1) \\
37 & = 2 \times 4 \times 5 - 3 \times 1 \\
38 & = 2 \times 4 \times 5 - 3 + 1 \\
39 & = (5 + 4 \times 2 ) \times 3 \times 1 \\
40 & = (5 + 4 \times 2 ) \times 3 + 1 \\
41 & = (4 + 5 \times 2 ) \times 3 - 1 \\
42 & = (4 + 5 \times 2 ) \times 3 \times 1 \\
43 & = (4 + 5 \times 2 ) \times 3 + 1 \\
44 & = (1+2+3+5) \times 4 \\
45 & = 3 \times 5 \times (4 - 2 +1) \\
46 & = (5 \times 4 + 3 ) \times 2 \times 1 \\
47 & = (5 \times 4 + 3 ) \times 2 + 1 \\
48 & = 2^4 \times (5-3+1) \\
49 & = (5+2) \times (4+3) \times 1 \\
50 & = (5+2) \times (4+3) + 1 \\
51 & = (5 \times 4 - 3) \times (2+1) \\
52 & = (3 \times 5 - 2) \times 4 \times 1 \\
53 & = (3 \times 5 - 2) \times 4 + 1 \\
54 & = (5 \times 4 - 2) \times 3 \times 1 \\
55 & = (5 \times 4 - 2) \times 3 + 1 \\
56 & = (5+3 -1) \times 4^2 \\
57 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  -2 -1 \\
58 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  -2 \times 1 \\
59 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  -2 +1 \\
60 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)   \times (2 -1) \\
61 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  + 2 - 1 \\
62 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  + 2 \times  1 \\
63 & = (5 \times 4 \times 3)  + 2 + 1 \\
64 & = 2^5 \times (4-3) \times 1 \\
65 & = 2^5 \times (4-3) + 1 \\
66 & = 2^5 + 4-3+1 \\
67 & = 4! \times 3 - 5 \times (2-1) \\
68 & = 4! \times 3 - 5 + (2-1) \\
69 & = (4+3) \times 5 \times 2 -1 \\
70 & = (4+3) \times 5 \times 2 \times 1 \\
71 & = (4+3) \times 5 \times 2 + 1 \\
72 & = 4! \times (5-2) \times 1^3 \\
73 & = 4! \times (5-2) + 1^3 \\
74 & = 5^2 \times 3 - 1^4 \\
75 & = 5^2 \times 3 \times 1^4 \\
76 & = 5^2 \times 3 + 1^4 \\
77 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
78 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 1^2 \\
79 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 2 \times 1 \\
80 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 2 + 1 \\
81 & = 3^{4-1} \times (5-2) \\
82 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 2 \times 1 \\
83 & = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 2 + 1 \\
84 & = 3^4 + 5 - 2 \times 1 \\
85 & = 3^4 + 5 - 2 + 1 \\
86 & = 3^4 + 5 \times 1^2 \\
87 & = 3^4 + 5 + 1^2 \\
88 & = 3^4 + 5 +2^1 \\
89 & = 3^4 + 5 + 2 + 1 \\
90 & = 3^2 \times 5  \times 2^1 \\
91 & = 3^2 \times 5  \times 2 + 1 \\
92 & = 3^4 + 5 \times 2 + 1 \\
93 & = 2^5 \times 3 +1 - 4 \\
94 & = 5^2 \times 4 - 3! \times 1 \\
95 & = 5^2 \times 4 - 3! + 1 \\
96 & = 5^2 \times 4 - 3 - 1 \\
97 & = 5^2 \times 4 - 3 \times 1 \\
98 & = 5^2 \times 4 - 3 + 1 \\
99 & = 5^2 \times 4 -1^3 \\
100 & = 5^2 \times 4 \times 1^3
\end{align}$

Someone please double check it.

Comment: You are quicker. Haha :)

Comment: Just leave me a few more minutes.

Comment: Tip: Use Factorial! (3! = 6) (4! = 24) (5! = 120)

Comment: I'm done. Can someone please double check it.

Comment: While trying to check whether we have any similarities, I noticed that you have missed the `3` in 72 and 73. You can fit it easily, though. :)

Comment: Thanks Maria for the heads up and boboquack for the edit. That was my intent in the first place, but I was in a hurry and missed it.

Answer (score 17):

$ 0 =  3^2 \times 1 - 4 - 5 $
$ 1 = 3^2 + 1 - 4 - 5 $
$ 2 = (4 - 5 + 3)/ 1^2 $
$ 3 = (5 + 4) \times 1 - 2 \times 3 $
$ 4 = (5 + 3) \times 1^2 - 4 $
$ 5 = 5 \times 2 - 4 - 1^3 $
$ 6 = 3 \times 2 + 5 - 1 - 4 $
$ 7 = 5 \times 2 - 3 \times 1^4 $
$ 8 = 4 + 5 - 3 + 2^1 $
$ 9 = 3^2 - 4 - 1 + 5 $
$ 10 = 5 \times 2 - 4 + 1 + 3 $
$ 11 = 5 + 3 + 4 - 1^2 $
$ 12 = 4 \times 5 \times 1 - 2^3 $
$ 13 = 4 \times 5 - 1 - 3 \times 2 $
$ 14 = 4 \times 5 - 3 \times 2 \times 1 $
$ 15 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 $
$ 16 = 4 + 5 + 2 \times 3 + 1 $
$ 17 = 5 + 3 + 2 \times 4 + 1 $
$ 18 = 5 + 4 + 1 + 2^3 $
$ 19 = 5 + 4 + 1 + 3^2 $
$ 20 = 5 \times 4 - 3 + 2 + 1 $
$ 21 = 5 \times 4 + 3 - 2 \times 1 $
$ 22 = 5 \times 4  + 3 - 2 + 1 $
$ 23 = 4 \times 3 + 5 \times 2 + 1 $
$ 24 = 5 \times 4 + 2 \times (3 - 1) $
$ 25 = 5 \times 4 + 3 + 2 \times 1 $
$ 26 = 5 \times 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 $
$ 27 = 5 \times 4 + 3 \times 2 + 1 $
$ 28 = 5 \times 4 \times 1 + 2^3 $
$ 29 = 5 \times 4 \times 1 + 3^2 $
$ 30 = 5 \times 4 + 3^2 + 1 $
$ 31 = 5 \times (4 + 2) + 1^3 $
$ 32 = 5 \times (4+2) + 3 - 1 $
$ 33 = 5 \times (4+2) + 3 \times 1 $
$ 34 = 5 \times (4+2) + 3 + 1 $
$ 35 = 5 \times 3 \times 2 + 4 + 1 $
$ 36 = 5 \times (4+2) \times 1 + 3! $
$ 37 = 5 \times (4+2) + 3! + 1 $
$ 38 = 4! + 2 \times 5 + 3 + 1 $
$ 39 = 2^5 + 4 + 3 \times 1 $
$ 40 = 2^5 + 4 + 3 + 1 $
$ 41 = 5 \times 2^3 + 1^4 $
$ 42 = 5 \times 3^2 + 4 - 1 $
$ 43 = 5 \times 2^3 + 4 - 1 $
$ 44 = 5 \times 2^3 + 4 \times 1 $
$ 45 = 5 \times 2^3 + 4 + 1 $
$ 46 = 5 \times 4 \times 2 \times 1 + 3! $
$ 47 = 5 \times 3(4 - 1) + 2 $   or $ 5 \times 4 \times 2 + 1 + 3! $
$ 48 = 4! \times 2 \times 1^3 $
$ 49 = 4! \times 2 + 1^{3+5} $
$ 50 = 4! \times 2 + 3 - 1^5 $ or $ 5 \times (4+3+2+1) $
$ 51 = 4! \times 2 \times 1^5 + 3 $
$ 52 = 4! \times 2 + 3 + 1^5 $
$ 53 = 4! \times 2 + 5 \times 1^3 $
$ 54 = 4! \times 2 + 5 + 1^3 $
$ 55 = 4! \times 2 + 5 + 3 - 1 $
$ 56 = 4! \times 2 + 5 + 3 \times 1 $
$ 57 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 - 1 - 2 $ or $ 4! \times 2 + 5 + 3 + 1 $
$ 58 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 - 2 \times 1 $
$ 59 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 - 2 + 1 $
$ 60 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 1^2 $
$ 61 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 - 1 + 2 $
$ 62 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 + 2 \times 1 $
$ 63 = 5 \times 4 \times 3 + 1 + 2 $
$ 64 = 2^5  \times  (4 - 3 + 1) $
$ 65 = 4! \times 3 - 5 - 2 \times 1 $
$ 66 = 4! \times 3 - 5 - 2 + 1 $
$ 67 = 4! \times 3 - 5 \times 1^2 $
$ 68 = 4! \times 3 - 5 - 1 + 2 $
$ 69 = 4! \times 3 - 5 + 2 \times 1 $
$ 70 = 4! \times 3 - 5 + 2 + 1 $
$ 71 = 4! \times 3 - 1^{5+2} $
$ 72 = 4! \times 3 \times 1^{5+2} $
$ 73 = 4! \times 3 + 1^{5+2} $
$ 74 = 4! \times 3 + 2 \times 1^5 $
$ 75 = 4! \times 3 \times 1 + 5 - 2 $
$ 76 = 4! \times 3 + 5 - 2 + 1  $
$ 77 = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 1^2 $
$ 78 = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 1^2 $
$ 79 = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 2 \times 1 $
$ 80 = 4! \times 3 + 5 + 2 + 1 $
$ 81 = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 2 - 1 $
$ 82 = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 2 \times 1 $
$ 83 = 4! \times 3 + 5 \times 2 + 1 $
$ 84 = 3^4 + 5 - 2 \times 1 $
$ 85 = 3^4 + 5 - 1^2 $
$ 86 = 3^4 + 5 \times 1^2 $
$ 87 = 3^4 + 5 + 1^2 $
$ 88 = 3^4 + 5 + 2 \times 1 $
$ 89 = 3^4 + 5 + 2 + 1 $
$ 90 = 3^4 + 5 \times 2 - 1 $
$ 91 = 3^4 + 5 \times 2 \times 1 $
$ 92 = 3^4 + 5 \times 2 + 1 $
$ 93 = 4! \times (3 + 1) - 5 + 2 $
$ 94 = 4! \times (5 - 1^3) - 2 $
$ 95 = 4! \times (5 + 3)/2 - 1 $
$ 96 = 4! \times 1 \times (5+3)/2 $
$ 97 = 4! \times (5+3)/2 + 1 $
$ 98 = 4! \times (5-1^3) + 2 $
$ 99 = 4! \times (5-1^2) + 3 $
$ 100 = 5 \times 4 \times (3+2) \times 1 $
$ 101 = 5 \times 4 \times (3+2) + 1 $

Comment: I don't want to nitpick but it says numbers 0-100. You can add 0 at the top to make it legal.

Comment: Oops copy pasting error - I did have it.

Comment: Uhm, yes, I figured it was bugging it. I will reformat it when I get home later. For now, I would leave it like that - it is a little off, but visible.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a program in Python 3:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import combinations, chain, product
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv, pow
import random

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def powerset(s):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)))

operations = [
    ('+', add),
    ('-', sub),
    ('*', mul),
    ('/', truediv),
    ('**', pow),
]

def bracket(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        return '(' + s + ')'
    return s

def sample(s):
    return random.sample(s, min(len(s), 5))

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def calculate(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        num = nums[0]
        return {num: str(num)}
    answer = defaultdict(set)
    for left_parts in powerset(nums):
        right_parts = tuple(x for x in nums if x not in left_parts)
        for (left_num, left_strings), (right_num, right_strings) in product(
                calculate(left_parts).items(),
                calculate(right_parts).items()):
            for op_str, op_func in operations:
                orders = [list]
                if op_str not in '+*':
                    orders += [reversed]
                for order in orders:
                    try:
                        result_num = op_func(*order([left_num, right_num]))
                    except (ZeroDivisionError, OverflowError):
                        continue
                    if isinstance(result_num, complex) or abs(result_num) > 1000:
                        continue
                    for left_string, right_string in product(sample(left_strings),
                                                             sample(right_strings)):
                        result_string = '{1} {0} {2}'.format(op_str,
                                                             *order([bracket(left_string),
                                                                     bracket(right_string)]))
                        assert eval(result_string) == result_num
                        answer[result_num].add(result_string)

    return answer

def main():
    answer = calculate((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    nums = sorted(num for num in answer if int(num) == num and num >= 0)
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        if num != i:
            break
        print(int(num), '=',
              '  or  '.join(sample(answer[num]))
              .replace('**', '^')
              .replace('*', '×'))

main()
```

It uses addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation (x to the power of y), and parentheses. It gives up to 5 solutions for each number from 1 up to 177. It could give solutions for many more numbers but you'd start to see gaps, since apparently you can't make 178. Unfortunately it's not smart enough to tell when two solutions are essentially the same, so there's often lots of very similar looking solutions for a particular number, although I tried to mix them up. You can also get more solutions per number, but when I tried with 7 I hit the character limit in my answer.

```
0 = (2 + 3) - (5 ^ (1 ^ 4))  or  (3 ^ 2) - (4 + (5 × 1))  or  (((5 + 3) / 4) / 2) - 1  or  ((1 + 2) / 3) + (4 - 5)  or  (3 - (1 + 2)) ^ (4 / 5)
1 = 1 ^ (4 ^ (3 - (2 × 5)))  or  1 ^ (4 × (2 × (3 / 5)))  or  (1 - 2) ^ ((5 ^ 3) × 4)  or  1 ^ (5 + (4 + (2 - 3)))  or  (3 × 1) / (2 - (4 - 5))
2 = (1 + (3 - 2)) ^ (5 - 4)  or  2 - (5 ^ ((1 - 4) ^ 3))  or  ((1 ^ 5) ^ 3) × (4 - 2)  or  (3 - 1) / (4 + (2 - 5))  or  (3 - 4) - ((2 × 1) - 5)
3 = 3 ^ ((5 - 4) ^ (2 ^ 1))  or  (5 - 4) + ((1 + 3) / 2)  or  2 × (3 / ((5 - 4) + 1))  or  ((1 + 3) + 5) - (2 + 4)  or  (4 + 3) + ((2 - 5) - 1)
4 = (1 / 2) ^ (5 - (4 + 3))  or  (3 / 1) + (2 - (5 - 4))  or  (3 - (4 - 5)) / (2 - 1)  or  (4 + 3) - (2 + (1 ^ 5))  or  (2 - (5 - 3)) + (1 × 4)
5 = (4 + 5) - (3 - (1 - 2))  or  (3 - (1 + 5)) + (2 × 4)  or  (5 × 3) / ((4 + 1) - 2)  or  (5 + 3) - (1 - (2 - 4))  or  ((4 / 2) + 3) / (1 ^ 5)
6 = (4 × 3) + (1 - (5 + 2))  or  (3 × 4) + (1 - (5 + 2))  or  (4 × 3) - ((1 ^ 2) + 5)  or  (3 / (1 - 4)) + (2 + 5)  or  (2 - 5) × ((1 ^ 4) - 3)
7 = ((5 + 2) / (3 + 1)) × 4  or  (5 + 4) - (2 / (1 ^ 3))  or  (5 + (4 - 2)) × (1 ^ 3)  or  ((5 × 2) / (1 ^ 4)) - 3  or  (1 × 5) - (4 - (3 × 2))
8 = 3 + (5 ^ (4 - (2 + 1)))  or  ((2 × 3) - 4) × (5 - 1)  or  (1 × 5) + ((2 - 3) + 4)  or  2 + ((5 + (4 - 3)) × 1)  or  ((5 + 1) + 2) × (4 - 3)
9 = (3 ^ 2) - (4 - (5 - 1))  or  (4 × 1) - (5 / (2 - 3))  or  (5 + 2) - (4 / (1 - 3))  or  (1 ^ (3 / 5)) + (4 × 2)  or  3 - (((2 - 5) + 1) - 4)
10 = 2 + ((4 × (1 + 5)) / 3)  or  (5 × (1 ^ 3)) × (4 - 2)  or  (5 + (3 - 2)) + (4 ^ 1)  or  (5 - 4) + (3 ^ (2 / 1))  or  (3 + 1) / ((4 - 2) / 5)
11 = (4 - (2 - 1)) + (5 + 3)  or  ((3 × 5) - 4) × (1 ^ 2)  or  (3 ^ 2) - ((4 - 5) - 1)  or  (5 + 4) - ((2 - 1) - 3)  or  (3 + (2 × 4)) ^ (1 ^ 5)
12 = (1 × 2) × (5 + (4 - 3))  or  (5 × 4) - ((1 × 2) ^ 3)  or  ((5 + 1) × 2) × (4 - 3)  or  ((1 + 5) × (2 ^ 3)) / 4  or  (3 × ((5 - 1) ^ 2)) / 4
13 = (3 + ((4 + 2) - 1)) + 5  or  (3 + 1) × (2 + (5 / 4))  or  (2 + (4 + 3)) - (1 - 5)  or  (5 + (2 + 3)) + (4 - 1)  or  ((5 - (1 + 2)) ^ 4) - 3
14 = (5 - (2 - (3 × 4))) - 1  or  (2 ^ 4) + ((1 ^ 5) - 3)  or  (3 - 1) × ((4 + 5) - 2)  or  ((4 + (3 + 5)) + 2) / 1  or  (2 × (4 + 3)) ^ (1 ^ 5)
15 = (3 × 2) + ((4 + 5) ^ 1)  or  (1 × (5 + 4)) + (3 × 2)  or  ((4 + 5) × 2) - (3 ^ 1)  or  1 - ((5 - (4 ^ 2)) - 3)  or  (2 ^ 4) + (3 - (5 - 1))
16 = ((5 × 3) + 4) - (1 + 2)  or  ((4 × 3) + 1) + (5 - 2)  or  (3 + 5) / (2 × (1 / 4))  or  (5 + (4 × 2)) + (1 × 3)  or  (4 + (5 - 1)) + (2 ^ 3)
17 = 1 - (((3 - 5) × 4) × 2)  or  (3 ^ 4) - (2 ^ (5 + 1))  or  (5 × 3) - ((2 - 4) / 1)  or  2 - (5 × ((1 ^ 3) - 4))  or  ((2 + 5) × 3) - (4 / 1)
18 = (4 × 3) × ((5 / 2) - 1)  or  ((5 × 3) + 1) + (4 - 2)  or  (5 × 4) - ((1 + 3) - 2)  or  (5 × 3) + (1 - (2 - 4))  or  (2 + 4) + ((5 - 1) × 3)
19 = ((5 ^ (3 - 1)) - 2) - 4  or  (2 × 5) - (3 × (1 - 4))  or  (2 - 3) + ((1 × 5) × 4)  or  ((4 × 3) + 2) + (5 ^ 1)  or  (4 / (2 - 1)) + (5 × 3)
20 = (1 + 5) × (2 + (4 / 3))  or  ((5 × 4) + 3) - (2 + 1)  or  (4 × 2) / (1 - (3 / 5))  or  (2 ^ 4) / ((3 + 1) / 5)  or  (3 - 1) + (2 × (5 + 4))
21 = 3 - ((2 / 1) - (4 × 5))  or  ((5 × 1) - 2) × (4 + 3)  or  (3 ^ 1) × (5 - (2 - 4))  or  (5 × 4) - ((1 ^ 3) - 2)  or  ((5 × 4) + 3) - (1 × 2)
22 = ((5 × (2 + 1)) + 3) + 4  or  (2 + 5) + (3 × (4 + 1))  or  ((5 × 3) - (4 / 1)) × 2  or  (3 + (5 + (4 - 1))) × 2  or  ((3 × 1) × 4) + (2 × 5)
23 = (4 ^ 2) + (3 + (5 - 1))  or  ((2 × 4) + (5 × 3)) / 1  or  (2 × 5) + ((4 × 3) + 1)  or  (3 - 1) - (4 - (5 ^ 2))  or  1 - (3 - (5 ^ (4 / 2)))
24 = ((2 ^ 4) + (3 × 1)) + 5  or  (2 ^ 1) × ((5 + 4) + 3)  or  (5 ^ 2) - (4 - (3 ^ 1))  or  (3 × 1) + ((4 ^ 2) + 5)  or  ((2 × 4) × 3) / (1 ^ 5)
25 = ((2 + 3) × 5) × (1 ^ 4)  or  (3 + (5 × 4)) + (2 × 1)  or  ((3 × (2 ^ 5)) / 4) + 1  or  ((2 × 5) ^ (3 - 1)) / 4  or  5 + ((3 + (2 ^ 4)) + 1)
26 = (1 × 4) + ((5 ^ 2) - 3)  or  (4 + 1) + (3 × (5 + 2))  or  (2 × 3) + (4 × (5 × 1))  or  (3 ^ (1 + 2)) + (4 - 5)  or  ((2 × 3) × (5 / 1)) - 4
27 = 1 / (3 ^ ((4 - 5) - 2))  or  (3 × 1) ^ ((4 × 2) - 5)  or  (2 × (3 ^ 4)) / (5 + 1)  or  ((5 - 2) ^ 4) / (3 ^ 1)  or  (2 - (4 - 5)) ^ (1 × 3)
28 = (4 × (5 + 2)) × (1 ^ 3)  or  (5 + 2) × ((1 ^ 3) × 4)  or  ((4 × 5) ^ 1) + (2 ^ 3)  or  (5 × (3 + 2)) - (1 - 4)  or  (4 + (5 ^ 2)) - (1 ^ 3)
29 = (2 + 3) + (4 × (1 + 5))  or  (2 × (4 × 3)) + (1 × 5)  or  ((4 / 2) ^ 5) - (3 ^ 1)  or  (1 × 5) + ((2 × 3) × 4)  or  (1 ^ 4) + (3 + (5 ^ 2))
30 = ((1 + 4) × (3 + 2)) + 5  or  (4 × 3) × ((5 ^ 1) / 2)  or  ((4 / 2) + 3) × (1 + 5)  or  ((5 + 2) + 3) × (4 - 1)  or  (1 - ((2 - 4) ^ 5)) - 3
31 = (2 × 3) + ((1 + 4) × 5)  or  (4 ^ (5 / 2)) - (1 ^ 3)  or  1 × (4 - ((2 - 5) ^ 3))  or  ((4 × (2 + 1)) × 3) - 5  or  ((4 + 1) × 5) + (3 × 2)
32 = (4 × (5 + 3)) ^ (2 - 1)  or  (2 ^ 5) × (4 - (3 / 1))  or  (2 × 4) × (3 + (1 ^ 5))  or  (2 / 1) × ((3 - 5) ^ 4)  or  2 / (1 × (4 ^ (3 - 5)))
33 = 1 - ((2 / (3 - 4)) ^ 5)  or  (4 / 1) + ((2 ^ 5) - 3)  or  (2 ^ 5) - (3 - (1 × 4))  or  (4 + (5 + 2)) × (3 × 1)  or  ((2 ^ 5) - (3 - 4)) / 1
34 = (3 - 1) - ((2 - 4) ^ 5)  or  ((1 - 3) + 4) + (2 ^ 5)  or  ((4 / 2) ^ 5) + (3 - 1)  or  ((4 + 1) × 5) + (3 ^ 2)  or  2 - (((3 - 4) - 1) ^ 5)
35 = (2 × ((3 × 4) + 5)) + 1  or  (1 × 3) - ((2 - 4) ^ 5)  or  5 / ((1 ^ 2) / (4 + 3))  or  (1 + ((4 ^ 3) + 5)) / 2  or  ((4 / 2) ^ 5) + (1 × 3)
36 = 4 × ((3 + 5) + (1 ^ 2))  or  (5 × 4) + ((3 + 1) ^ 2)  or  ((5 + 4) + 3) × (2 + 1)  or  (4 + 2) × ((1 ^ 3) + 5)  or  (3 × (5 - 2)) × (1 × 4)
37 = ((3 + 1) × (2 × 4)) + 5  or  ((5 × 2) × 4) - (3 × 1)  or  ((2 × 5) × 4) - (3 ^ 1)  or  (((2 × 5) ^ 1) × 4) - 3  or  (5 / (1 / (4 + 3))) + 2
38 = (3 × (5 + (4 × 2))) - 1  or  (2 ^ 1) × (4 + (5 × 3))  or  (2 / 1) × (4 + (3 × 5))  or  ((4 + (3 × 5)) × 2) × 1  or  ((3 - 1) ^ 5) + (2 + 4)
39 = (1 + (3 × 4)) × (5 - 2)  or  (5 × (2 × 4)) - (1 ^ 3)  or  3 / (1 / (5 + (2 × 4)))  or  (((2 ^ 5) + 3) + 4) ^ 1  or  1 - ((5 - (3 ^ 4)) / 2)
40 = (2 / ((1 ^ 3) / 4)) × 5  or  ((5 / 1) + (2 + 3)) × 4  or  5 / ((2 / (4 × 1)) ^ 3)  or  (3 + 2) × ((4 - 1) + 5)  or  ((3 + 5) + 2) × (1 × 4)
41 = ((5 ^ 3) - 2) / (4 - 1)  or  1 × (((3 ^ 2) × 4) + 5)  or  (4 × (3 ^ 2)) + (5 ^ 1)  or  (1 ^ 3) + (5 × (4 × 2))  or  (2 × ((4 × 5) - 1)) + 3
42 = (3 × ((5 × 2) + 4)) × 1  or  (2 + 4) × (5 - (1 - 3))  or  2 × ((5 ^ (3 - 1)) - 4)  or  (2 + 5) × ((4 + 3) - 1)  or  1 + ((4 × (3 ^ 2)) + 5)
43 = (((2 ^ 4) × 3) / 1) - 5  or  (3 + ((5 × 2) × 4)) ^ 1  or  ((3 × (4 ^ 2)) - 5) × 1  or  1 / (2 / (5 + (3 ^ 4)))  or  (3 × 1) + ((5 × 2) × 4)
44 = (2 ^ 5) + (3 × (4 / 1))  or  (4 ^ 1) × (5 + (2 × 3))  or  (3 + ((5 × 4) × 2)) + 1  or  4 / (1 / (5 + (2 × 3)))  or  (2 ^ 5) + ((3 / 1) × 4)
45 = (4 + 5) × ((2 / 1) + 3)  or  (4 + 5) / (1 / (2 + 3))  or  (3 × 4) + (1 + (2 ^ 5))  or  (1 + (4 - 2)) × (5 × 3)  or  (3 + 2) × (4 + (1 × 5))
46 = (2 / 1) × (3 + (4 × 5))  or  (3 × (1 + (4 ^ 2))) - 5  or  ((2 + 3) × (5 + 4)) + 1  or  (2 × (3 + (4 × 5))) × 1  or  (2 / 1) × (3 + (5 × 4))
47 = (5 × 4) + (3 ^ (2 + 1))  or  3 + ((1 + (2 × 5)) × 4)  or  2 + (((4 - 1) × 3) × 5)  or  (2 × ((5 × 4) + 3)) + 1  or  ((1 + 4) × 3) + (2 ^ 5)
48 = (3 + 1) × (4 × (5 - 2))  or  ((2 + 4) × (3 + 5)) × 1  or  ((5 + 4) - 1) × (2 × 3)  or  ((5 - 3) ^ 4) × (1 + 2)  or  (4 + 2) × ((3 + 5) ^ 1)
49 = ((2 + 5) × 1) × (3 + 4)  or  ((5 - (3 × 4)) ^ 2) / 1  or  (5 - (4 × 3)) ^ (2 / 1)  or  (3 + 4) ^ (2 × (1 ^ 5))  or  (1 - (5 + 3)) ^ (4 - 2)
50 = 5 × ((4 + (1 + 3)) + 2)  or  ((3 - (1 / 2)) × 5) × 4  or  ((4 × 3) - 2) / (1 / 5)  or  ((4 + 1) ^ 3) × (2 / 5)  or  (5 × 1) × (4 + (2 × 3))
51 = ((4 ^ 2) + (1 ^ 5)) × 3  or  (2 + 1) × ((4 × 3) + 5)  or  ((3 × 4) + 5) × (1 + 2)  or  3 + (4 × ((5 + 1) × 2))  or  (5 × (4 + (3 × 2))) + 1
52 = (5 - 1) + (3 × (4 ^ 2))  or  (4 × 1) × (3 + (2 × 5))  or  (5 + ((2 ^ 4) × 3)) - 1  or  (5 + (4 × 2)) × (1 + 3)  or  (3 ^ (4 - 1)) + (5 ^ 2)
53 = 1 + (4 × (3 + (5 × 2)))  or  (5 + ((2 ^ 4) × 3)) ^ 1  or  (4 × (3 + (5 × 2))) + 1  or  5 + (1 × ((4 ^ 2) × 3))  or  (5 / 1) + ((4 ^ 2) × 3)
54 = (5 + 1) + (3 × (2 ^ 4))  or  (3 × 1) × ((5 + 4) × 2)  or  (1 + 5) × ((3 + 2) + 4)  or  (3 × (5 - (1 / 2))) × 4  or  ((4 + 5) / 1) × (2 × 3)
55 = (4 + 1) × ((3 × 2) + 5)  or  (1 × 5) × (3 + (4 × 2))  or  (5 × (3 + (2 × 4))) / 1  or  ((4 ^ 3) + 1) - (2 × 5)  or  ((3 × 2) + 5) × (1 + 4)
56 = (3 ^ 4) - (5 ^ (2 / 1))  or  ((3 ^ 1) ^ 4) - (5 ^ 2)  or  (2 × (3 + 4)) × (5 - 1)  or  (2 + 5) × ((1 + 4) + 3)  or  (3 + 5) × ((2 + 4) + 1)
57 = ((4 ^ 3) - (5 + 2)) ^ 1  or  ((2 ^ (1 + 5)) - 4) - 3  or  ((5 × (2 + 1)) × 4) - 3  or  (4 ^ (1 × 3)) - (2 + 5)  or  (((4 × 5) - 2) + 1) × 3
58 = 4 + ((3 ^ 2) × (5 + 1))  or  ((5 + 1) × (3 ^ 2)) + 4  or  (1 + ((4 ^ 3) - 5)) - 2  or  (((3 × 5) - 1) × 4) + 2  or  (3 × (5 × 4)) - (2 × 1)
59 = (((3 + 5) ^ 2) - 1) - 4  or  (4 ^ 3) - (5 ^ (2 - 1))  or  (4 ^ 3) - (5 / (1 ^ 2))  or  ((5 × (4 × 3)) - 2) + 1  or  (1 ^ 2) × ((4 ^ 3) - 5)
60 = (5 × (3 ^ (1 ^ 2))) × 4  or  (5 ^ 1) × ((2 ^ 3) + 4)  or  (3 × (4 × 5)) × (1 ^ 2)  or  ((1 ^ 2) × 4) × (3 × 5)  or  ((4 ^ 3) - 1) - (5 - 2)
61 = ((2 - 5) / 1) + (4 ^ 3)  or  (4 ^ (5 - 2)) - (3 ^ 1)  or  (4 ^ (3 × 1)) + (2 - 5)  or  (2 / 1) - (5 - (4 ^ 3))  or  (1 × 2) + ((4 ^ 3) - 5)
62 = ((4 ^ (1 ^ 5)) ^ 3) - 2  or  1 + ((4 ^ 3) + (2 - 5))  or  1 - ((5 - (4 ^ 3)) - 2)  or  1 × (2 + ((5 × 4) × 3))  or  ((4 ^ (2 + 1)) - 5) + 3
63 = (3 × 1) × ((5 ^ 2) - 4)  or  3 - (4 - (2 ^ (5 + 1)))  or  (3 × (5 + (2 ^ 4))) / 1  or  (5 × (4 × 3)) + (1 + 2)  or  (3 × (5 × 4)) + (2 + 1)
64 = (2 ^ (4 + 1)) × (5 - 3)  or  (2 × 4) / (1 / (5 + 3))  or  (3 + (1 ^ 5)) × (4 ^ 2)  or  (1 ^ 3) × (4 ^ (5 - 2))  or  (4 × 2) ^ ((5 - 3) / 1)
65 = ((3 ^ 2) + 4) × (5 ^ 1)  or  (5 ^ 1) × ((2 ^ 4) - 3)  or  ((5 × 2) + 3) × (4 + 1)  or  4 + ((2 ^ (1 + 5)) - 3)  or  (3 × (2 + (4 × 5))) - 1
66 = 4 × ((5 + (1 / 2)) × 3)  or  4 - (2 + ((1 - 5) ^ 3))  or  2 × ((4 × (5 + 3)) + 1)  or  ((4 / (1 ^ 5)) ^ 3) + 2  or  (4 / 2) + ((5 - 1) ^ 3)
67 = ((4 ^ 3) + 5) - (1 × 2)  or  ((1 ^ 5) + (4 ^ 3)) + 2  or  1 + ((2 + (5 × 4)) × 3)  or  (5 - 2) + (4 ^ (3 ^ 1))  or  (4 ^ 3) + ((5 - 2) / 1)
68 = 5 + ((4 ^ 3) - (1 ^ 2))  or  1 - ((2 - 5) - (4 ^ 3))  or  ((5 × 3) + 2) × (4 ^ 1)  or  ((3 × 5) + 2) × (4 × 1)  or  ((3 × 5) + 2) × (4 / 1)
69 = (4 ^ 3) - (5 × (1 - 2))  or  1 + (((5 × 3) + 2) × 4)  or  (1 + 2) × ((4 × 5) + 3)  or  ((4 ^ 3) + 5) × (1 ^ 2)  or  (((4 + 3) × 5) × 2) - 1
70 = (2 / 1) × ((3 + 4) × 5)  or  ((3 ^ 4) - (5 × 2)) - 1  or  (5 × ((3 + 4) × 2)) ^ 1  or  5 × ((2 / 1) + (4 × 3))  or  (4 + 3) × (1 × (2 × 5))
71 = (5 + (4 ^ 3)) + (2 × 1)  or  (3 ^ 4) - (5 / (1 / 2))  or  (3 ^ 4) - (5 × (2 / 1))  or  (3 ^ 4) - (2 / (1 / 5))  or  (3 ^ (4 / 1)) - (2 × 5)
72 = (5 + (2 - 1)) × (3 × 4)  or  (4 + (2 ^ 3)) × (1 + 5)  or  (2 ^ 3) × (4 + (1 × 5))  or  (2 + 5) + ((4 ^ 3) + 1)  or  (3 × (5 ^ 2)) + (1 - 4)
73 = ((3 ^ 4) - 1) - (2 + 5)  or  ((3 ^ 4) - (1 + 2)) - 5  or  ((3 × 5) × (4 + 1)) - 2  or  ((3 ^ 4) - (2 + 1)) - 5  or  ((5 + 4) × (2 ^ 3)) + 1
74 = ((5 × 2) + (4 ^ 3)) ^ 1  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 5) - 2) ^ 1  or  (5 × 2) + ((4 ^ 1) ^ 3)  or  1 × ((5 × 2) + (4 ^ 3))  or  (3 ^ (4 ^ 1)) - (5 + 2)
75 = 3 × ((1 × 5) ^ (4 - 2))  or  (1 + ((3 ^ 4) - 2)) - 5  or  ((4 - 1) + 2) × (5 × 3)  or  (5 × (4 - 1)) × (3 + 2)  or  (1 + (3 ^ 4)) - (5 + 2)
76 = ((2 ^ 4) + 3) × (5 - 1)  or  (3 / (5 ^ (2 - 4))) + 1  or  ((5 × (2 ^ 4)) - 1) - 3  or  ((2 ^ 4) × 5) - (3 + 1)  or  (3 × (5 ^ 2)) + (1 ^ 4)
77 = (5 × (4 ^ 2)) - (3 / 1)  or  (((2 ^ 4) × 5) × 1) - 3  or  ((3 ^ 4) - 1) + (2 - 5)  or  ((4 ^ 2) / (1 / 5)) - 3  or  ((5 × 2) + 1) × (3 + 4)
78 = 3 × ((5 ^ (4 - 2)) + 1)  or  (4 × (5 × (3 + 1))) - 2  or  (((5 + 4) ^ 2) - 3) ^ 1  or  ((5 × (4 ^ 2)) - 3) + 1  or  (((2 - 5) ^ 1) ^ 4) - 3
79 = (2 + (1 - 5)) + (3 ^ 4)  or  (1 + ((5 + 4) ^ 2)) - 3  or  (3 ^ 4) - ((1 ^ 5) × 2)  or  ((3 ^ 4) - 2) ^ (1 ^ 5)  or  ((1 + 2) ^ 4) - (5 - 3)
80 = (5 × (2 × (3 - 1))) × 4  or  ((2 - (1 - 3)) × 5) × 4  or  (2 ^ 3) × ((4 + 1) + 5)  or  (3 ^ 4) - (1 ^ (2 ^ 5))  or  (((4 + 1) ^ 2) × 3) + 5
81 = (4 + 5) ^ ((3 - 2) + 1)  or  ((4 ^ 2) × 5) + (1 ^ 3)  or  ((3 + 1) + 5) ^ (4 / 2)  or  ((1 + (4 / 2)) ^ 5) / 3  or  ((2 ^ 3) + 1) × (4 + 5)
82 = (5 × (1 + (4 ^ 2))) - 3  or  (5 × ((3 - 1) ^ 4)) + 2  or  (3 × ((5 ^ 2) + 1)) + 4  or  (1 ^ 3) + ((2 - 5) ^ 4)  or  (((2 ^ 4) + 1) × 5) - 3
83 = 5 + ((3 ^ 4) - (2 + 1))  or  (3 + (5 × (4 ^ 2))) ^ 1  or  ((3 ^ 4) + (5 - 1)) - 2  or  (5 + (3 ^ 4)) - (1 + 2)  or  (3 + ((4 ^ 2) × 5)) × 1
84 = ((4 × (5 + 2)) ^ 1) × 3  or  (4 × (5 + 2)) × (3 / 1)  or  (4 ^ 1) × (3 × (5 + 2))  or  (5 + 2) / ((1 / 3) / 4)  or  1 + (3 + (5 × (2 ^ 4)))
85 = (3 + 1) + ((5 + 4) ^ 2)  or  ((5 - 2) ^ 4) + (1 + 3)  or  (1 + ((3 ^ 4) - 2)) + 5  or  (3 + ((5 + 4) ^ 2)) + 1  or  ((5 - 2) ^ 4) + (3 + 1)
86 = (3 ^ 4) - (5 / (1 - 2))  or  (((5 ^ 2) + 4) × 3) - 1  or  (((5 - 1) ^ 4) + 2) / 3  or  5 - ((1 - 2) × (3 ^ 4))  or  (((1 - 5) ^ 4) + 2) / 3
87 = 2 - ((1 - (3 ^ 4)) - 5)  or  2 + (5 + ((3 ^ 4) - 1))  or  2 - ((1 - 5) - (3 ^ 4))  or  ((3 ^ 4) + 2) - (1 - 5)  or  (3 ^ 4) + (5 + (1 ^ 2))
88 = ((5 ^ 2) - 3) × (4 ^ 1)  or  (2 + (5 + (3 ^ 4))) ^ 1  or  (2 + (3 ^ 4)) + (1 × 5)  or  ((1 + (2 ^ 4)) × 5) + 3  or  ((5 + (3 ^ 4)) + 2) × 1
89 = (2 + (3 ^ 4)) + (1 + 5)  or  (3 ^ (5 - 1)) + (4 × 2)  or  (4 ^ (3 ^ 1)) + (5 ^ 2)  or  1 - ((3 - (5 ^ 2)) × 4)  or  (((1 + 2) ^ 4) + 5) + 3
90 = (1 + (3 ^ 2)) × (4 + 5)  or  ((4 + 2) × 1) × (5 × 3)  or  2 × (3 × ((4 - 1) × 5))  or  ((4 + 2) × 5) × (3 / 1)  or  (3 × (4 + 2)) × (5 / 1)
91 = 1 + ((3 × 5) × (4 + 2))  or  ((3 × (2 ^ 5)) - 1) - 4  or  (3 ^ (1 × 4)) + (5 × 2)  or  (((2 ^ 5) × 3) - 4) - 1  or  (5 × 2) + (3 ^ (4 × 1))
92 = (1 + (3 ^ 4)) + (5 × 2)  or  (3 ^ 4) + (1 + (2 × 5))  or  (((5 ^ 2) + 1) - 3) × 4  or  (((5 ^ 2) - 3) + 1) × 4  or  1 × ((3 × (2 ^ 5)) - 4)
93 = (((4 - 2) ^ 5) - 1) × 3  or  (1 + (5 × (4 + 2))) × 3  or  ((1 + 5) × 2) + (3 ^ 4)  or  3 × (1 + (5 × (2 + 4)))  or  (((4 / 2) ^ 5) - 1) × 3
94 = (5 × ((2 ^ 4) + 3)) - 1  or  (5 × (3 + (4 ^ 2))) - 1  or  (((4 ^ 2) + 3) × 5) - 1  or  (5 × ((4 ^ 2) + 3)) - 1  or  (((2 ^ 4) + 3) × 5) - 1
95 = ((4 × 5) - 1) × (3 + 2)  or  ((2 ^ 5) + (4 ^ 3)) - 1  or  ((2 ^ 4) + 3) × (5 / 1)  or  ((3 + (4 ^ 2)) × 5) ^ 1  or  (1 × 5) × ((4 ^ 2) + 3)
96 = (5 - 1) × (3 × (2 × 4))  or  (2 ^ 5) × ((1 ^ 4) × 3)  or  ((2 + 1) + 5) × (3 × 4)  or  ((5 × 3) + 1) × (2 + 4)  or  ((4 × 2) × 3) × (5 - 1)
97 = (((5 ^ 2) × 4) - 3) × 1  or  ((5 ^ 2) × 4) - (3 × 1)  or  (2 ^ 4) + (3 ^ (5 - 1))  or  ((5 ^ 2) × (4 / 1)) - 3  or  ((5 ^ 2) × 4) - (3 ^ 1)
98 = (4 × (5 ^ 2)) + (1 - 3)  or  ((4 × (5 ^ 2)) - 3) + 1  or  1 - (3 - ((5 ^ 2) × 4))  or  (4 × (5 ^ 2)) - (3 - 1)  or  (((5 ^ 2) × 4) + 1) - 3
99 = ((2 ^ 4) × (5 + 1)) + 3  or  ((1 + 5) × (2 ^ 4)) + 3  or  (4 + ((2 ^ 5) × 3)) - 1  or  3 × ((1 ^ 4) + (2 ^ 5))  or  ((3 + 2) × (5 × 4)) - 1
100 = (((2 + 3) × 5) × 4) ^ 1  or  ((5 × 4) ^ 2) / (3 + 1)  or  (2 + 3) × (5 / (1 / 4))  or  ((3 + 2) × 4) × (1 × 5)  or  (4 / 1) × (5 × (2 + 3))
101 = ((5 ^ 2) × 4) + (1 ^ 3)  or  (1 + 4) + (3 × (2 ^ 5))  or  (((5 ^ 2) + 1) × 4) - 3  or  1 + (((2 ^ 5) × 3) + 4)  or  ((2 ^ 5) × 3) + (1 + 4)
102 = (3 + ((5 ^ 2) × 4)) - 1  or  3 + (((5 ^ 2) × 4) - 1)  or  2 + (4 × (5 ^ (3 - 1)))  or  3 - (1 - ((5 ^ 2) × 4))  or  (3 - 1) + (4 × (5 ^ 2))
103 = ((5 ^ 2) × 4) + (3 / 1)  or  (((5 ^ 2) × 4) / 1) + 3  or  3 + (4 × ((5 ^ 2) × 1))  or  (1 × 3) + (4 × (5 ^ 2))  or  (4 × (5 ^ 2)) + (3 / 1)
104 = 1 + (3 + ((5 ^ 2) × 4))  or  (3 + (1 / 4)) × (2 ^ 5)  or  (((2 + 3) × 5) + 1) × 4  or  (((3 - 1) × 5) ^ 2) + 4  or  ((4 × (5 ^ 2)) + 3) + 1
105 = (4 + 3) × ((1 + 2) × 5)  or  (5 ^ 2) - (1 - (3 ^ 4))  or  (5 + 2) × ((1 + 4) × 3)  or  (3 × (5 + 2)) × (4 + 1)  or  (1 + 4) × ((2 + 5) × 3)
106 = ((3 × 1) ^ 4) + (5 ^ 2)  or  (3 ^ 4) + ((5 / 1) ^ 2)  or  (5 ^ 2) + (3 ^ (4 / 1))  or  ((5 ^ 2) / 1) + (3 ^ 4)  or  ((3 ^ 4) + (5 ^ 2)) / 1
107 = (((2 ^ 5) + 4) × 3) - 1  or  3 + ((1 + (5 ^ 2)) × 4)  or  (((5 ^ 2) + 1) × 4) + 3  or  (3 ^ 4) + ((5 ^ 2) + 1)  or  1 + ((5 ^ 2) + (3 ^ 4))
108 = (4 + 2) × (3 × (5 + 1))  or  ((5 - 2) ^ 3) × (4 × 1)  or  (3 × 4) × ((5 × 2) - 1)  or  ((5 + 1) × 3) × (4 + 2)  or  2 × (((5 + 1) ^ 3) / 4)
109 = (5 ^ 3) - (4 ^ (2 ^ 1))  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 ^ 2)) ^ 1  or  1 + (4 × (3 ^ (5 - 2)))  or  ((1 × 5) ^ 3) - (2 ^ 4)  or  (5 ^ 3) - ((2 ^ 4) / 1)
110 = 5 × (((4 + 1) ^ 2) - 3)  or  (2 × 5) × ((3 × 4) - 1)  or  (((4 + 1) ^ 2) - 3) × 5  or  (5 ^ 3) + (1 - (2 ^ 4))  or  (((3 × 4) - 1) × 5) × 2
111 = ((3 + (5 ^ 2)) × 4) - 1  or  (4 + (1 + (2 ^ 5))) × 3  or  ((4 + 1) + (2 ^ 5)) × 3  or  3 × (((2 ^ 5) + 4) + 1)  or  3 × (((2 ^ 5) + 1) + 4)
112 = (3 + (5 ^ 2)) × (4 ^ 1)  or  (4 × (3 + (5 ^ 2))) ^ 1  or  (3 ^ 4) + ((2 ^ 5) - 1)  or  2 × (4 × ((3 × 5) - 1))  or  (4 × (2 + 5)) × (1 + 3)
113 = (4 × ((2 + 1) ^ 3)) + 5  or  ((3 ^ 4) / 1) + (2 ^ 5)  or  ((1 × 2) ^ 5) + (3 ^ 4)  or  ((2 ^ 5) + (3 ^ 4)) ^ 1  or  ((2 ^ 5) × 1) + (3 ^ 4)
114 = ((4 ^ 2) + 3) × (5 + 1)  or  (2 ^ 5) + (1 + (3 ^ 4))  or  (1 + (2 ^ 5)) + (3 ^ 4)  or  (3 + (2 ^ 4)) × (1 + 5)  or  1 + ((3 ^ 4) + (2 ^ 5))
115 = 5 × (((1 + 2) ^ 3) - 4)  or  5 × ((2 × (3 × 4)) - 1)  or  (4 × ((2 ^ 5) - 3)) - 1  or  (((3 × 2) × 4) - 1) × 5  or  5 × (((2 × 4) × 3) - 1)
116 = (3 + ((5 ^ 2) + 1)) × 4  or  4 × (1 × ((2 ^ 5) - 3))  or  (4 × 1) × ((2 ^ 5) - 3)  or  (((3 × 4) - 1) ^ 2) - 5  or  2 × ((4 ^ 3) - (1 + 5))
117 = ((5 ^ 3) ^ 1) - (2 × 4)  or  ((1 × 5) ^ 3) - (2 × 4)  or  (5 ^ 3) - (4 × (2 × 1))  or  1 × ((5 ^ 3) - (4 × 2))  or  ((5 ^ 3) × 1) - (2 × 4)
118 = (((3 ^ 5) + 1) / 2) - 4  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (2 + 4)) - 1  or  1 + ((5 ^ 3) - (2 × 4))  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 + 2)) - 1  or  (((5 ^ 3) - 4) - 2) - 1
119 = (5 ^ (4 - 1)) - (2 × 3)  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 + 2)) / 1  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 × 1)) - 2  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 / 1)) - 2  or  ((5 ^ 3) - 2) - (1 × 4)
120 = ((2 + (4 - 1)) ^ 3) - 5  or  2 / (((1 / 3) / 5) / 4)  or  (1 × 4) × (2 × (5 × 3))  or  (1 × (4 × 5)) × (3 × 2)  or  (2 × 3) × ((4 ^ 1) × 5)
121 = (4 × (1 - 2)) + (5 ^ 3)  or  (4 - (3 × 5)) ^ (2 / 1)  or  ((5 × 3) - 4) ^ (2 ^ 1)  or  (5 - (2 ^ 4)) ^ (3 - 1)  or  ((2 + 4) + 5) ^ (3 - 1)
122 = (2 × (4 ^ 3)) - (1 + 5)  or  ((5 ^ 3) + 2) - (4 + 1)  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 5) + 1)) / 4  or  ((3 ^ 5) + 1) / (4 - 2)  or  ((5 ^ 3) - (4 + 1)) + 2
123 = ((2 ^ (3 + 4)) - 5) ^ 1  or  1 × (((5 ^ 3) + 2) - 4)  or  ((5 ^ 3) - 4) + (2 ^ 1)  or  (((5 ^ 3) + 2) × 1) - 4  or  (2 / 1) - (4 - (5 ^ 3))
124 = (2 + 1) + ((5 ^ 3) - 4)  or  (2 + (5 ^ 3)) + (1 - 4)  or  3 + ((5 ^ (2 + 1)) - 4)  or  2 + ((5 ^ 3) + (1 - 4))  or  ((5 ^ 3) + 2) - (4 - 1)
125 = (5 × (3 + 2)) × (1 + 4)  or  ((5 ^ 4) / 1) / (3 + 2)  or  ((3 + 2) ^ 4) / (5 × 1)  or  (5 ^ 1) ^ (4 + (2 - 3))  or  (5 / (3 - 2)) ^ (4 - 1)
126 = (5 ^ (2 + 1)) + (4 - 3)  or  2 × ((4 ^ 3) - (1 ^ 5))  or  4 - ((2 - (5 ^ 3)) + 1)  or  4 + ((5 ^ (1 + 2)) - 3)  or  (3 × ((4 × 5) + 1)) × 2
127 = (4 / 2) + (1 × (5 ^ 3))  or  (4 - (2 - (5 ^ 3))) ^ 1  or  (4 + ((5 ^ 3) - 2)) ^ 1  or  ((5 × 1) ^ 3) + (4 / 2)  or  (5 ^ 3) + ((4 / 2) ^ 1)
128 = ((4 ^ 3) × 2) / (1 ^ 5)  or  (2 ^ (4 + 3)) × (1 ^ 5)  or  ((3 + 5) × (2 ^ 4)) ^ 1  or  1 + ((5 ^ 3) - (2 - 4))  or  (3 - 1) ^ (5 + (4 - 2))
129 = (1 ^ 5) + (2 × (4 ^ 3))  or  ((2 - 1) × (5 ^ 3)) + 4  or  ((1 + (2 ^ 5)) × 4) - 3  or  1 + (2 ^ ((4 × 3) - 5))  or  (2 ^ ((4 × 3) - 5)) + 1
130 = (3 + (5 ^ (4 - 1))) + 2  or  (5 × (1 + (3 × 4))) × 2  or  (5 ^ 3) + ((4 + 2) - 1)  or  5 × (2 × ((3 × 4) + 1))  or  (((2 ^ 5) × 4) - 1) + 3
131 = (4 × (2 ^ 5)) + (1 × 3)  or  ((4 + (5 ^ 3)) + 2) ^ 1  or  (1 × 3) + ((2 ^ 5) × 4)  or  5 - ((1 - (4 ^ 3)) × 2)  or  (1 × (5 ^ 3)) + (2 + 4)
132 = (2 ^ (4 + 3)) + (5 - 1)  or  5 + (2 + ((1 + 4) ^ 3))  or  2 + (1 + (4 + (5 ^ 3)))  or  ((5 ^ 3) + 4) + (1 + 2)  or  (((5 × 2) + 1) × 3) × 4
133 = ((5 ^ 3) + (4 × 2)) ^ 1  or  (5 ^ 1) + ((4 ^ 3) × 2)  or  (((4 ^ 3) × 2) + 5) / 1  or  ((2 ^ (4 + 3)) + 5) / 1  or  (5 + ((4 ^ 3) × 2)) × 1
134 = ((2 ^ (4 + 3)) + 1) + 5  or  (5 ^ 3) + ((4 × 2) + 1)  or  (2 ^ (3 + 4)) + (1 + 5)  or  ((4 ^ 3) × 2) + (1 + 5)  or  (5 + ((4 ^ 3) × 2)) + 1
135 = ((2 + 1) ^ 4) × (5 / 3)  or  5 × (((2 + 1) ^ 4) / 3)  or  5 / (3 / ((2 + 1) ^ 4))  or  3 × (5 × (1 + (2 × 4)))  or  ((2 × 4) + 1) × (5 × 3)
136 = (1 + (4 ^ 2)) × (5 + 3)  or  2 × (((5 - 1) ^ 3) + 4)  or  4 × (3 + ((2 ^ 5) - 1))  or  (1 + (4 ^ 2)) × (3 + 5)  or  2 × ((5 + (4 ^ 3)) - 1)
137 = (5 × (3 ^ (4 - 1))) + 2  or  ((3 ^ (4 - 1)) × 5) + 2  or  (4 × (2 + 1)) + (5 ^ 3)  or  2 - (5 × ((1 - 4) ^ 3))  or  (3 × 4) + (5 ^ (2 + 1))
138 = (2 × (5 + (4 ^ 3))) × 1  or  (((4 ^ 3) + 5) × 2) × 1  or  (1 × 2) × ((4 ^ 3) + 5)  or  (2 × ((4 ^ 3) + 5)) × 1  or  2 × (5 + ((4 / 1) ^ 3))
139 = ((5 + (4 ^ 3)) × 2) + 1  or  ((4 × 3) ^ 2) - (5 / 1)  or  1 × (((3 × 4) ^ 2) - 5)  or  (((2 ^ 5) + 3) × 4) - 1  or  4 + ((3 ^ (1 + 2)) × 5)
140 = (5 ^ 3) - (1 - (2 ^ 4))  or  ((5 ^ 3) - 1) + (4 ^ 2)  or  (5 × 4) × (1 + (3 × 2))  or  (((2 ^ 5) + 3) × 4) ^ 1  or  5 × (((3 × 2) + 1) × 4)
141 = ((3 + (2 ^ 5)) × 4) + 1  or  ((2 ^ 4) + (5 ^ 3)) / 1  or  (5 ^ 3) + ((1 × 2) ^ 4)  or  (2 ^ 4) + (5 ^ (3 / 1))  or  (5 ^ 3) + (4 ^ (2 ^ 1))
142 = ((4 ^ 2) + 1) + (5 ^ 3)  or  (4 ^ 2) + (1 + (5 ^ 3))  or  (1 + (4 ^ 2)) + (5 ^ 3)  or  (2 ^ 4) + (1 + (5 ^ 3))  or  ((5 ^ 3) + (2 ^ 4)) + 1
143 = (((4 + 3) + 5) ^ 2) - 1  or  ((4 + (5 + 3)) ^ 2) - 1  or  ((4 + (3 + 5)) ^ 2) - 1  or  ((5 + (4 + 3)) ^ 2) - 1  or  (((3 + 5) + 4) ^ 2) - 1
144 = (((3 + 5) + 4) ^ 2) × 1  or  (3 × ((5 + 1) × 4)) × 2  or  (5 + (4 + 3)) ^ (2 ^ 1)  or  (2 ^ (3 + 1)) × (4 + 5)  or  (1 + 5) × ((2 × 4) × 3)
145 = 1 + ((5 + (4 + 3)) ^ 2)  or  (1 ^ 5) + ((3 × 4) ^ 2)  or  (4 + 1) × ((2 ^ 5) - 3)  or  (1 ^ 5) + ((4 × 3) ^ 2)  or  1 + ((3 + (5 + 4)) ^ 2)
146 = ((3 ^ (2 + 4)) + 1) / 5  or  (1 + (3 ^ (2 + 4))) / 5  or  (1 + (3 ^ (4 + 2))) / 5  or  ((3 ^ (4 + 2)) + 1) / 5
147 = (((4 × 5) + 1) ^ 2) / 3  or  3 + (4 × ((5 + 1) ^ 2))  or  3 + (((1 + 5) ^ 2) × 4)  or  (((1 + 5) ^ 2) × 4) + 3  or  (((5 + 1) ^ 2) × 4) + 3
148 = ((3 × (1 - 5)) ^ 2) + 4  or  5 + (((3 × 4) ^ 2) - 1)  or  (((1 - 5) × 3) ^ 2) + 4  or  5 + (((4 × 3) ^ 2) - 1)  or  (((3 × 4) ^ 2) - 1) + 5
149 = (((3 × 4) × 1) ^ 2) + 5  or  (5 + ((3 × 4) ^ 2)) ^ 1  or  (5 + ((4 × 3) ^ 2)) ^ 1  or  ((4 × 3) ^ 2) + (5 × 1)  or  1 × (((3 × 4) ^ 2) + 5)
150 = 5 × ((4 + 1) × (3 × 2))  or  ((1 + 4) × 2) × (5 × 3)  or  ((4 × 3) ^ 2) + (5 + 1)  or  (2 × 5) × (3 × (1 + 4))  or  3 × ((5 × (1 + 4)) × 2)
151 = (2 × ((3 ^ 4) - 5)) - 1  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 5) × 2) - 1
152 = ((4 × 5) - 1) × (2 ^ 3)  or  2 × ((3 ^ (4 × 1)) - 5)  or  ((3 ^ 4) - 5) × (1 × 2)  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 5) × 2) × 1  or  (2 ^ 3) × ((5 × 4) - 1)
153 = 1 - (2 × (5 - (3 ^ 4)))  or  1 - ((5 - (3 ^ 4)) × 2)  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 5) × 2) + 1  or  1 + (((3 ^ 4) - 5) × 2)  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 4) - 5)) + 1
154 = ((1 - 5) + (3 ^ 4)) × 2  or  2 × (1 + ((3 ^ 4) - 5))  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 5) + 1) × 2  or  2 × ((1 + (3 ^ 4)) - 5)  or  ((3 ^ 4) + (1 - 5)) × 2
155 = (4 + ((1 + 2) ^ 3)) × 5  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 4) - 1)) - 5  or  ((3 ^ (1 + 2)) + 4) × 5  or  5 × (4 + ((1 + 2) ^ 3))  or  (4 + (3 ^ (1 + 2))) × 5
156 = ((3 ^ 4) × 2) - (1 + 5)  or  4 × (((5 + 1) ^ 2) + 3)  or  4 × (((1 + 5) ^ 2) + 3)  or  (((3 ^ 4) × 2) - 1) - 5  or  4 × ((5 × (2 ^ 3)) - 1)
157 = ((2 × (3 ^ 4)) - 5) / 1  or  ((3 ^ (4 / 1)) × 2) - 5  or  ((2 ^ (1 + 4)) × 5) - 3  or  ((3 ^ 4) / (1 / 2)) - 5  or  (((3 ^ 4) × 2) - 5) / 1
158 = (1 - 5) + ((3 ^ 4) × 2)  or  (((3 ^ 4) × 2) + 1) - 5  or  (2 × (3 ^ (5 - 1))) - 4  or  (1 + ((3 ^ 4) × 2)) - 5  or  ((2 × (3 ^ 4)) - 5) + 1
159 = (2 × (1 + (3 ^ 4))) - 5  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 4) + 1)) - 5  or  (5 / (2 / (4 ^ 3))) - 1  or  (((3 ^ 4) + 1) × 2) - 5  or  ((5 × (4 ^ 3)) / 2) - 1
160 = 1 × ((2 ^ 3) × (5 × 4))  or  (5 × (3 + 1)) × (2 × 4)  or  ((5 × (4 ^ 3)) × 1) / 2  or  4 × ((1 + 3) × (5 × 2))  or  5 / (2 / (4 ^ (1 × 3)))
161 = 1 + ((5 × 4) × (2 ^ 3))  or  ((3 ^ 4) × 2) - (1 ^ 5)  or  (5 × ((4 ^ 3) / 2)) + 1  or  ((5 × (2 ^ 3)) × 4) + 1  or  (2 × (3 ^ 4)) - (1 ^ 5)
162 = (3 - 1) × ((4 + 5) ^ 2)  or  (3 ^ 5) / ((2 / 4) + 1)  or  ((1 + 2) ^ 4) × (5 - 3)  or  (2 × ((4 - 1) ^ 5)) / 3  or  (3 ^ 4) × (5 - (2 + 1))
163 = 3 + (5 × (2 ^ (4 + 1)))  or  3 + ((2 ^ 5) × (1 + 4))  or  ((2 ^ (1 + 4)) × 5) + 3  or  3 + ((2 ^ 5) × (4 + 1))  or  ((3 ^ 4) × 2) + (1 ^ 5)
164 = ((1 ^ 5) + (3 ^ 4)) × 2  or  4 × (1 + (5 × (2 ^ 3)))  or  ((3 ^ 4) + (1 ^ 5)) × 2  or  ((1 + (3 × 4)) ^ 2) - 5  or  (((2 ^ 3) × 5) + 1) × 4
165 = (((3 ^ 4) - 1) × 2) + 5  or  5 × (1 + ((4 ^ 3) / 2))  or  (1 + ((4 ^ 3) / 2)) × 5  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 4) - 1)) + 5  or  ((4 × (2 ^ 3)) + 1) × 5
166 = 5 - (1 - ((3 ^ 4) × 2))  or  (2 × (3 ^ (5 - 1))) + 4  or  4 + (2 × (3 ^ (5 - 1)))  or  (2 / (3 ^ (1 - 5))) + 4  or  (5 - 1) + (2 × (3 ^ 4))
167 = (5 + (2 × (3 ^ 4))) ^ 1  or  ((2 × 1) × (3 ^ 4)) + 5  or  5 + (1 × (2 × (3 ^ 4)))  or  5 + ((3 ^ 4) × (2 / 1))  or  ((3 ^ 4) × 2) + (1 × 5)
168 = ((4 × 5) + 1) × (2 ^ 3)  or  (4 + 3) × ((5 ^ 2) - 1)  or  (1 + ((3 ^ 4) × 2)) + 5  or  ((5 ^ 2) - 1) × (3 + 4)  or  (2 × (3 ^ 4)) + (1 + 5)
169 = (1 + ((5 + 3) + 4)) ^ 2  or  ((3 + 4) + (1 + 5)) ^ 2  or  ((5 + (3 + 4)) + 1) ^ 2  or  ((1 + (3 ^ 4)) × 2) + 5  or  ((3 × 4) + (1 ^ 5)) ^ 2
170 = 2 × ((3 ^ 4) + (5 - 1))  or  (((3 ^ 4) - 1) + 5) × 2  or  2 × ((3 ^ 4) - (1 - 5))  or  ((3 ^ 4) - (1 - 5)) × 2  or  2 × (((3 ^ 4) - 1) + 5)
171 = (3 ^ 2) × ((4 × 5) - 1)  or  ((4 × 5) - 1) × (3 ^ 2)  or  ((2 ^ (5 + 4)) + 1) / 3  or  ((5 × 4) - 1) × (3 ^ 2)  or  (2 × ((3 ^ 4) + 5)) - 1
172 = 1 × (((3 ^ 4) + 5) × 2)  or  (1 × 2) × ((3 ^ 4) + 5)  or  2 × (((3 ^ 4) + 5) × 1)  or  (((3 ^ 4) + 5) × 2) / 1  or  1 × (2 × (5 + (3 ^ 4)))
173 = 1 + (2 × ((3 ^ 4) + 5))  or  1 + (((3 ^ 4) + 5) × 2)  or  1 + (2 × (5 + (3 ^ 4)))  or  (((3 ^ 4) + 5) × 2) + 1  or  1 + ((5 + (3 ^ 4)) × 2)
174 = (5 + (1 + (3 ^ 4))) × 2  or  ((4 + 3) × (5 ^ 2)) - 1  or  (((4 × 3) + 1) ^ 2) + 5  or  5 + ((1 + (4 × 3)) ^ 2)  or  (((3 ^ 4) + 1) + 5) × 2
175 = ((3 + 4) × (5 ^ 2)) ^ 1  or  1 × ((4 + 3) × (5 ^ 2))  or  ((3 + 4) × (5 ^ 2)) × 1  or  5 × (((3 ^ 2) × 4) - 1)  or  (1 + 4) × (3 + (2 ^ 5))
176 = 4 × (((3 ^ 2) × 5) - 1)  or  1 + ((4 + 3) × (5 ^ 2))  or  1 + ((5 ^ 2) × (4 + 3))  or  ((5 ^ 2) × (3 + 4)) + 1  or  ((3 + 4) × (5 ^ 2)) + 1
```

Comment: Good job.  Add the solution for zero [0-100] to have a complete answer.

Comment: Nice job! I wonder what the maximum is!

Comment: Awesome. But I recommend you (post-process) to a) sort the solutions from L-to-R to reward expressions using only simple arithmetic, and penalize ^ and ! Because `0 = (1+2-3) x (4+5)` is much nicer than `(3 - (1 + 2)) ^ (4 / 5)`. And `(3 ^ 2) - (4 + (5 × 1))` is pretty good though. ...

Comment: ...and b) to remove the unnecessary nested parentheses due to commutativity in `((5 + 2) + 3)`. And `(5 + (3 ^ 4))` can be simplified and made visually clearer as `(5 + 3^4)`. Some of your exponentiation solutions are really hard to read...

Comment: @AllanCao the maximum will be something like [`2^(3^(4^(5+1)))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(3%5E(4%5E(5%2B1)))) which is **huge**. The program has to be restricted from producing even mildly large numbers because it wouldn't be able to handle trying to calculate the exponentiations of them.

Comment: You're awesome! Great work

Comment: @AlexHall I've tried to calculate it. the exponent for 2^x has 1954 digits. That's essentially googol^20. And then you have that many 2s. And yet, you can make it even bigger than that by doing `(2^(3^(4^(5+1))))!`, which is that massive number exponentiated.