# Express numbers 1 - 100 using only 1, 2, 3, and 4

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

The least number that cannot be written using the numbers 1, 2, and 3, each exactly once, and any combination of standard arithmetic operations (including factorials) is 41. **What is the least such number if the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4 are allowed?**

Allowed operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, factorials, exponents, square roots, intermediate non-integer results, and any amount of parentheses and brackets. No other digits besides one of each of 1, 2, 3, and 4.

(This is basically [what user Bernardo Recamán Santos asked 4 years ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40339/expressing-numbers-using-0-1-2-3-and-4) but just without using 0. I have all the numbers except 86 and 93...)

Comment: Is concatenation allowed?

Comment: So, for example, if you can have concatenation, you could just do $86 = 43 \times 2$. Do you think this is okay? Also, do you have a reference for the $1,2,3$ version as this might help.

Comment: @KentoHarmel so this is a homework assignment?

Comment: Is Decimal point ( using say .4) allowed? If yes I have a solution

Comment: If 19 is possible with just 1, 2 and 3, then 76 is possible by multiplying that result by 4. I'll admit I'm not coming with the former easily.

Comment: This does not help for extra solutions, but I find it remarkable that 64 can be made with {3,4}, with {2,4} and with {2,3}.

Comment: I think "41" was just copied from the 0,1,2,3,(4) question. I don't think this is true for 1,2,3 (even with concatenation).

Comment: Sorry guys for the confusion, there are no concatenations allowed.

Comment: Does Albert Lang's solution for 85 count?

Comment: Yes it does @hexomino

Comment: @KentoHarmel Okay, I've added solutions for 86 and 93 which are along the same lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create 76 out of 1,2,3,4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118708/create-76-out-of-1-2-3-4)

Answer (score 3):

91 is also possible without concatenation

> $((3!)!)/(2\times4) + 1$

Comment: What does "confirm yours" mean? Also, please put any math in MathJax.

Comment: I meant with that that I also found solutions for the numbers Kento solved. I guess that does not serve a purpose. I'll remove that part to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Here comes $76$:

> $76 = 4 \sqrt{\frac {(3!)!}{2}+1}$

If we are allowed double factorials we can do $85$:

> $85 = \frac{2^{4!!}-1}{3}$

Comment: 76: nice one, and in addition you upped the minimum.

Comment: Can you please explain 76 for me, I keep getting a number with decimals, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: @KentoHarmel Sure: $3!=6$, $6!=720$ $\frac{720}{2}=360$ $360+1=361$ $\sqrt{361}=19$ $4\times 19=76$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Albert.Lang

Answer (score 3):

An answer for $99$:

> $(3!+4)^2-1$

Regarding $85$, $86$, $93$:

> I think these are impossible without concatenation, double factorial (deemed acceptable by OP's comment), or other operations of unknown status. I could not find answers even with computer aid.
>
>
>  With concatenation:
>
>
>  $85 = 43 \times 2 - 1$ (based on hexomino's comment)
>
>
>  $86 = 43 \times 2 \times 1$ (based on hexomino's comment)
>
>
>  $93 = 12 + 3^4$

If arbitrary multifactorials are allowed, we can obtain any positive integer in a rather silly way:

> Suppose we want to reach $N$. Let $I(n, m)$ be the itererated factorial function, applying the ordinary factorial $m$ times starting with $n$. Choose $m$ such that $I(5, m) > 2N$. Then $$N = I(4+1, m)!^{(I(5, m) - N)} / I(2+3, m)$$ because $$I(5, m)!^{(I(5, m) - N)} = I(5, m) \times (I(5, m) - (I(5, m) - N)) = I(5, m) \times N$$ Note, the next term in the multifactorial expansion would be $$N - (I(5, m) - N) = 2N - I(5, m) < 0$$

Comment: Let $A=I(5, m)$. How come $A!^{A-N}=AN$? Something in your notation is unclear.

Comment: @RosieF $!^{(k)}$ (specifically with parentheses) denotes the $k$-th multifactorial, not a normal exponent. Not a great notation, but somewhat standard, if uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

Following Albert Lang's second solution, if we extend to double factorials, we can get $86$ and $93$

> $86 = ((3!)!! - 4 - 1) \times 2 $
>  $93 = ((3!)!! \times 2) - 4 + 1$

Comment: Wow, thank you, that's impressive